# State and localStorage data is different after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state

So I have a problem with state and localStorage. To be exact, whenever I nest the objects inside of the themes.dark and themes.light the results in dynamic codeblock differ after refresh even though the localStorage data is in fact correct.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import store from "store2";
import "./styles.css";

const themes = {
  dark: {
    theme: "dark"
  },
  light: {
    theme: "light"
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const defaultDarkTheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme:dark)")
    .matches
    ? themes.dark
    : themes.light;
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(store.get("theme") || defaultDarkTheme);

  useEffect(() => {
    store.set("theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="App"
        onClick={() =>
          theme === themes.dark ? setTheme(themes.light) : setTheme(themes.dark)
        }
      >
        {JSON.stringify(theme)}
      </div>
      {theme === themes.dark
        ? JSON.stringify(themes.dark)
        : JSON.stringify(themes.light)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Before refresh **:**

[image]

After refresh **:**

[image]

It's pretty problematic since after refresh instead of generating the content for dark mode it generates the content for the light one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your `useEffect` hook.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   store.set("theme", theme);
 }, [theme]);
```

I think your `useEffect` runs before it gets the data from the localStorage. I'm not sure this is just a hunch.

Comment: How can I make it to run before it then?

Comment: Try getting the theme data in `useEffect` instead of above `useEffect`

Comment: I already tried that before:
```(() => {setTheme(store.get('theme') || defaultDarkTheme)}, []);```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with state or the storage. You will see your problem if you add the following line after declaring your state and refresh the page after changing it to dark.
`console.log(theme, themes.dark, theme === themes.dark)`

Javascript only decides that two objects are equal if they refer to the exact same object. However when you get your theme object from the store, it is not the exact same object as the themes.dark object you've defined earlier.

There are multiple ways to handle a scenario like this, but I think it would be simplest if you compare some string properties of the objects, for example,

```
theme.theme === themes.dark.theme
        ? JSON.stringify(themes.dark)
        : JSON.stringify(themes.light)
```

alternatively you could define a unique identifier property on your theme object which you can use to compare instead of `theme.theme` or if you really want to compare the objects you could do something like

```
JSON.stringify(theme) === JSON.stringify(themes.dark)
        ? JSON.stringify(themes.dark)
        : JSON.stringify(themes.light)
```